# Dynamically update a table control in asp.net in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have project where I need to dynamically update the `Table` control based on a `button_click` event.

Every time the `Button` is clicked, the `Table` resets itself based on different inputs. The inputs come from a file which is uploaded by the client.(I did this with the file `Uploader` control). The client can essentially upload a different file every time and click the `Button` to reset the `Table` based on the inputs from the file.

```
try
{    
    Upload1003.PostedFile.SaveAs(@"path" + filename);
    parseAnswer = parse.parse(@"path", filename);
    Span1.InnerHtml = "File Upload Sucessful";     
}

catch (Exception)
{
    Span1.InnerHtml = "File Upload Error";
};

int col = 3;
int row = parseAnswer.getTotalItem();
Create1003Table(col, row, parseAnswer);
```

The `Table` only works on first click. The second clicks gives me an error:

`Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object`

I just started learning `C# and ASP.Net`. So I am not sure about what is causing this error.

Comment: related to this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978929/asp-error-operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object