# maximum value for aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys

Tags: asp.net

I have a form that posts pretty big data and i get this error

```
[InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the    object.]
   System.Web.HttpValueCollection.ThrowIfMaxHttpCollectionKeysExceeded() +2419334
   System.Web.HttpValueCollection.FillFromEncodedBytes(Byte[] bytes, Encoding encoding) +58
   System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +159

[HttpException (0x80004005): The URL-encoded form data is not valid.]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +217
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +104
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm() +9035903
   System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull) +97
   System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode() +69
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +135
```

To resolve this I got [this solution from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978929/asp-error-operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object) itself

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2000" />
</appSettings>
```

Now I would like to know the maximum valid value that could be set for `aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys`. Is there any problem in setting this key to its max value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can see the implementation of MaxHttpCollectionKeys in the [aspnetwebstack source](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/MediaTypeFormatter.cs) on GitHub.

From the implementation it seems like these are the limits:

1. MaxHttpCollectionKeys is an int, so it could have a max value of an integer (*int.MaxValue: 2,147,483,647*)
2. Minimum value is 1
3. Default value is 1000

This [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440(v=vs.120).aspx) recommends to not set MaxHttpCollectionKeys to a value too large as that would pose a security risk.
[image]

Comment: Hello, I've the same problem with a page that has a very long ListView. About 400 rows and about 10 controls per row that continues to grow. I've set MaxHttpCollectionKeys to 4000 but it doesn't works anyway. Can you suggest me a value to set? Thank you