# mvc post list with number of record not working

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am using MVC architecture for my application.

Now, I have more than 1000 record which i am binding on Listbox.kindly check below screen shot.[image]

Here, Left side list have more than 1000 records and my functionality is, User should select any record and move it to right side ListBox.

it;s work on my local system but when i deploy on iis6 web server it's giving me error. kindly check below image for error.

[image]

and also suppose i use less than 500 records.same functionality working properly.
so, i have to make changes on IIS or code or any limitation to post record on mvc?

Check Stack Trace

[image]

Comment: Where is the stack trace?

Comment: Probable duplicate, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978929/asp-error-operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object

Comment: What does your actual view markup look like?  I am surprised to see an `Object state` exception in an MVC application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are doing DoS attack on yourself. I think that you have 2 options:

- alter web config(ref. http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2012/01/19/operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of.aspx):

  ```
  <appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2000" /></appSettings>
  ```
- dont post whole form, just the part with data you need(carriers to be added). Either using jquery, or adding only fields to be posted inside form tag.